# Http get and post method without attribute name

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using .net Core 2.1 Web API. I add every method `[HttpGet("....")]` or `[HttpPost("....")]` like below. But, I don't want to write every method in every controller. I want to write only `[HttpGet]` or `[HttpPost]`. How can I achieve this?

Or, if this is not possible, can I do this like `[HttpPost("[action]")]` with taking automatically actionName?

I'm calling like this:
http://localhost:5000/api/University/GetUniversities

This working perfectly

```
namespace University.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UniversityController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUniversityService universityService;

        public UniversityController(IUniversityService universityService)
        {
            this.universityService = universityService;
        }

        [HttpGet("GetUniversities")]
        public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUniversities()
        {
            return await universityService.GetUniversities();
        }

        [HttpGet("GetUniversityStatues")]
        public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUniversityStatues()
        {
            return await universityService.GetUniversityStatues();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this but is not working:

```
namespace University.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UniversityController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IUniversityService universityService;

        public UniversityController(IUniversityService universityService)
        {
            this.universityService = universityService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUniversities()
        {
            return await universityService.GetUniversities();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUniversityStatues()
        {
            return await universityService.GetUniversityStatues();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply write `[HttpGet]` it will automatically fetch action name.

Comment: I tried but it's not going to method. @Justcode

Comment: what not working after edit? what your console is saying?

Comment: My console giving 404 error @Justcode

Comment: How do you call the api? show url

Comment: http://localhost:5000/api/University/GetUniversities from PostMan @MarcusHöglund

Comment: With just HttpGet, the url is localhost:5000/api/University

Comment: But a lot of action in my controller like `GetUniversities`, `GetStudent`, `GetUniversityStatus` etc. How my url know where to go? @MarcusHöglund

Comment: If you have more then one HttpGet method, then you need to define either the route in the attribute or the action name..Then you are back to square one

Comment: I thougt that C# can understand that taking automatically. But I understand that from your answer, c# is not clever as I hope. @MarcusHöglund

Comment: [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] is what I was looking for. This solved my issue. By this way, I can use without methodName even if more than one parameterless get  method. @MarcusHöglund C# is clever what I was hope :)

Comment: @HasanOzdemir haha great find!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web API like MVC has the convention over configuration, so if you didn't define the endpoint in the attribute, it will work but not as you expect. Generally Get method will be called like this api/[ControllerName] post method the same.

In your case, if you need to name your route the same name of your action you can write this attribute above your controller

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
```

Comment: But a lot of action in my controller like GetUniversities, GetStudent, GetUniversityStatus etc. How my url know where to go?@Jaffal

Comment: Based on parameters sent, if you have multiple get methods with the same parameters set I think you'll have an issue calling this API and that's why you'll need to define route names.

I believe you should not have all these methods in one controller, follow the RESTful API standards 
https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

Deal with entities as resources and each controller is responsible for one resource.

Comment: This is impossible for real scenario. Because, I think there will be more than 10.000 "get" action in my project. If I doing as you said, there will more than 10.000 controller. I think, it's not good thing. You can't manage 10.000 controller. @Jaffal

Comment: You got me wrong not a controller for each get method, but a controller for each entity e.g. University Controller, Students Controller, Grades Controller etc.

Comment: I understand. But for example, if we talk `universitycontroller`, there will be `getuniversities`, `getUniversityNames`, `getUniversityStatus`, `getUniversityLocationNames` etc. Every time will be more than one get or more than one post. One get operation never possible in real scenerio. I don't know, am I right?

Comment: Then you have to use routing check out my updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183110/discussion-between-jaffal-and-hasan-ozdemir).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jaffal. `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` was what I was looking for. It solved my issue. I can using [HttpGet] for more than one get method by this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use just [HttpGet]

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUniversities()
    {
        return await universityService.GetUniversities();
    }
```

And then send a get request to  http://localhost:5000/api/University. It will work fine.
But your problem is you have more than one parameterless get methods. then it can't identify which get method you need to call.

So if you really want to use two parameterless get methods in same controller you have to decorate it like this,

```
   [HttpGet("GetUniversities")]
   public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUniversities()
   {
       return await universityService.GetUniversities();
   }

   [HttpGet("GetUniversityStatues")]
   public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUniversityStatues()
   {
       return await universityService.GetUniversityStatues();
   }
```

Otherwise you have to move the second one to another controller

Comment: I have more than 100 parameterless "get" method in my controller in my real scenario @ThilinaSandunsiri. C# is not clever, as I thougt :( .

Comment: [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] is what I was looking for. This solved my issue. By this way, I can use without methodName even if more than one parameterless get  method. @ThilinaSandunsiri C# is clever what I was hope :)

Answer (score 0):

You can automate it a little by this

```
[HttpPost(nameof(GetUniversities))]
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not required to pass the method name with Http Verb. You can use like this also:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ServiceResult> GetUniversities()
        {
            return await universityService.GetUniversities();
        }
```

But you want to change the method name or route. You can something like this:

```
        [HttpGet("", Name="Students"]
        public async Task<ServiceResult> GetStudents()
        {
            return await universityService.GetStudents();
        }
```

Comment: I tried [HttpGet]. But it giving 404 error when I remove ("GetUniversities") @Sandeep